# Approximating finite differences by higher order derivatives of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, finite-differences, finite-difference-methods

In a mathematical physics exercise, some discrete fields can conveniently be expressed using finite difference schemes as follows:
\begin{align}
A_6 &= \phi_{i+1}+\phi_{i-1}+4\phi_i \, , \\
A_7 &= \phi_{i+2}+\phi_{i-2}-2\phi_i \, , \\
A_8 &= \phi_{i+2}-\phi_{i-2} \, , 
\end{align}
wherein $\phi_i \equiv \phi(x_i)$ such that $x_i = x_0 + ih$ are the node positions.
Moreover, $h$ represents a uniform grid spacing.
The goal is to approximate these groups by continuous functions following a standard discrete-to-continuum approach.

Here is what I have tried:
\begin{align}
A_6 &= \phi_{i+1}+\phi_{i-1}-2\phi_i + 6\phi_i \approx h^2 \phi''(x)+6\phi(x) \, , \\
A_7 &= \phi_{i+2}-4\phi_{i+1}+6\phi_i-4\phi_{i-1}+\phi_{i+2}
+4 \left( \phi_{i+1}+\phi_{i-1}-2\phi_i \right)
\approx h^2 \left( h^2\phi''''(x)+4 \phi''(x) \right) \, , \\
A_8 &= 2 \left( \frac{\phi_{i+2}}{2}-\phi_{i-1}+\phi_{i+1}- \frac{\phi_{i-2}}{2} +\phi_{i-1}-\phi_{i+1} \right)
\approx 2 h\left( h^2\phi'''(x) -2\phi'(x)\right) \, .
\end{align}

I'd like to know whether these approximations are unique and/or whether a better accuracy can be reached using different approaches.

Any help or comment is very welcome.

---

Here is a link to the wiki article on [finite difference coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient)

Comment: Just insert the Taylor expansion at $x_i$.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for the comment. Can you be more precise please? Taylor expansion of what?

Comment: Write $\phi_{i+r} = \exp(r h D)\phi(x)$ where $D$ is the differential operator and expand in powers of $h D$. E.g. $\phi_{i+1} + \phi_{i-1}= 2 \cosh(h D)\phi(x) = 2 \phi(x) + h^2 \phi''(x)+\cdots$.

Comment: @CountIblis Thanks iblis for your clarifications -- i got it :)